# OpenGL stopped rendering

Tags: opengl, rendering

First things first: Platform is Windows 7 64-bit, language is VC++, IDE is VS2010. Graphics card is nVidia GTX 460, drivers are version 290.53.

So here's the situation. I am currently working in OpenGL using Glew 1.7 and Glut. I set everything up a few days ago and managed to successfully code and complete an assignment for my classes. The assignment ran beautifully and displayed and did everything it was supposed to. That was wonderful. So I submitted my assignment and didn't touch it again until tonight.

Now, tonight I tried running the code again and instead of my beautifully tessellated polygons I am getting a plain white window. As far as I know, nothing related to OpenGL has changed on my system since I last ran the code. I haven't changed the code at all, I haven't changed the graphics drivers, I haven't changed anything that I am aware of. I couldn't seem to find anything related to this kind of problem, and I am at a loss of what could possibly be causing the issue. I even tried recompiling Glew, but it didn't change anything. I know it's not a code issue since it was working fine a few days ago and nothing has changed, so it has to be a configuration issue.

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

**Edit**
One more thing to add to this. When I was originally doing the project in question, attempting to run it produced the error message "unable to find glew32d.dll" until I placed glew32d.dll and glut32.dll in the source folder of my project.

Now, I don't remember deleting them from my project folder, but when I tried to debug it last night, I noticed that both of them had disappeared from my project folder. However, I was not getting any .dll missing errors. Replacing them in the folder didn't solve the problem, but I am wondering if their disappearance has something to do with this. They are also located in the VC/bin/ directory of the VS2010 install path, and deleting them from both locations produces the error message, but having them in either location is now sufficient for building and running when previously I needed them in both.

Comment: Just blind shot, but did you try to reinstall graphics card drivers..? Other OpenGL rendering works well..?

Comment: I just tried reinstalling the graphics card drivers. Unfortunately, it did not fix the issue. As far as I can tell, other OpenGL rendering seems to be fine.

Comment: So it seems to be in your code then ;].. Do you have some older version of your code..? Try them..

Comment: I tried re-running it with the code I submitted for the assignment, which I submitted right after my last successful run. Same results. I haven't changed anything since then. My professor is going to run the code as well and try to help me determine whether something funky is going on in my code, or if I'm just suffering from hallucinations of working output when attempting to compile gibberish.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that you're scaling by an infinite value (1.#INF), or something of the sort.  I've run into a very similar situation, and that turned out to be the problem.  However, if you have not changed the code, then you may be able to rule this out.  Have you tried throwing in some code to render a simple quad or triangle to the screen?

As for the .dlls, I recommend putting them in your C:/Windows/SysWOW64 and C:/Windows/System32 folders.  SysWOW64 specifically houses all the 32-bit .dlls, but it's safe to put them in both locations.  Visual Studio will look in both your project folder and these system folders for necessary dynamic libraries.  The advantage of placing them in the system folders is that they are then available for all OpenGL applications you may write.

One last thing that might help in finding the issue is making use of OpenGL's error reporting.  You can use a function such as:

```
void HandleGLError()
{
    GLenum error;
    int i = 0;
    while ((error = glGetError()) != GL_NO_ERROR) {
        printf("GL ERROR(%d) %s\n",i,gluErrorString(error));
        i++;
    }
}
```

Try calling that at the beginning and end of your render function, and in any other places you think might be causing a problem.